# query must begin with SELECT or FROM: delete [delete

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA in addition to spring(3.0.0.M4). While deleting multiple records using `query.executeUpdate()` i am getting the following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: delete [delete obj com.ocimum.btree.mw.core.objecttypes.profile.entity.ProfileEntity obj]
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:648)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:716)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I am using spring Transactional management.

Its working with `entityManager.remove()` but multiple delete is giving the above execption.
I hav't used any query factory in application.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem remains after correcting the syntax of your query, verify your Hibernate configuration:
Setting the property `hibernate.query.factory_class` to `org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` worked in my case.

For more information, I refer to the [Hibernate forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944696) where I found this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring. Your query syntax is incorrect, and the exception message is telling you that.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE [FROM] com.ocimum.btree.mw.core.objecttypes.profile.entity.ProfileEntity obj WHERE ...`

[Check here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)